# Installing curb (0.7.18) on ubuntu 12.10 with ruby 1.9.3p194

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.3, curb

I tried installing libcurl4-openssl-dev but didn't work. Does anyone had this kind of issue?
Here is the output of the bundle install.

```
Installing curb (0.7.18) with native extensions 
    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

         /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
    checking for curl-config... yes
    /usr/bin/curl-config: 138: /usr/bin/curl-config: CPPFLAG_CURL_STATICLIB: not found
    checking for curlinfo_redirect_time... yes
    checking for curlinfo_response_code... yes
    checking for curlinfo_filetime... yes
    checking for curlinfo_redirect_count... yes
    checking for curlinfo_os_errno... yes
    checking for curlinfo_num_connects... yes
    checking for curlinfo_ftp_entry_path... yes
    checking for curl_version_ssl... yes
    checking for curl_version_libz... yes
    checking for curl_version_ntlm... yes
    checking for curl_version_gssnegotiate... yes
    checking for curl_version_debug... yes
    checking for curl_version_asynchdns... yes
    checking for curl_version_spnego... yes
    checking for curl_version_largefile... yes
    checking for curl_version_idn... yes
    checking for curl_version_sspi... yes
    checking for curl_version_conv... yes
    checking for curlproxy_http... yes
    checking for curlproxy_socks4... yes
    checking for curlproxy_socks5... yes
    checking for curlauth_basic... yes
    checking for curlauth_digest... yes
    checking for curlauth_gssnegotiate... yes
    checking for curlauth_ntlm... yes
    checking for curlauth_anysafe... yes
    checking for curlauth_any... yes
    checking for curle_tftp_notfound... yes
    checking for curle_tftp_perm... yes
    checking for curle_tftp_diskfull... yes
    checking for curle_tftp_illegal... yes
    checking for curle_tftp_unknownid... yes
    checking for curle_tftp_exists... yes
    checking for curle_tftp_nosuchuser... yes
    checking for curle_send_fail_rewind... yes
    checking for curle_ssl_engine_initfailed... yes
    checking for curle_login_denied... yes
    checking for curlmopt_maxconnects... yes
    checking for curlopt_seekfunction... yes
    checking for curlopt_seekdata... yes
    checking for curlopt_sockoptfunction... yes
    checking for curlopt_sockoptdata... yes
    checking for curlopt_opensocketfunction... yes
    checking for curlopt_opensocketdata... yes
    checking for curle_conv_failed... yes
    checking for curle_conv_reqd... yes
    checking for curle_ssl_cacert_badfile... yes
    checking for curle_remote_file_not_found... yes
    checking for curle_ssh... yes
    checking for curle_ssl_shutdown_failed... yes
    checking for curle_again... yes
    checking for curle_ssl_crl_badfile... yes
    checking for curle_ssl_issuer_error... yes
    checking for curlopt_username... yes
    checking for curlopt_password... yes
    checking for curlinfo_primary_ip... yes
    checking for curlauth_digest_ie... yes
    checking for curlftpmethod_multicwd... yes
    checking for curlftpmethod_nocwd... yes
    checking for curlftpmethod_singlecwd... yes
    checking for curlm_bad_socket... yes
    checking for curlm_unknown_option... yes
    checking for curl_multi_timeout()... yes
    checking for curl_multi_fdset()... yes
    checking for curl_multi_perform()... yes
    checking for curlopt_interleavefunction... yes
    checking for curlopt_interleavedata... yes
    checking for curlopt_chunk_bgn_function... yes
    checking for curlopt_chunk_end_function... yes
    checking for curlopt_chunk_data... yes
    checking for curlopt_fnmatch_function... yes
    checking for curlopt_fnmatch_data... yes
    checking for curlopt_errorbuffer... yes
    checking for curlopt_stderr... yes
    checking for curlopt_failonerror... yes
    checking for curlopt_url... yes
    checking for curlopt_protocols... yes
    checking for curlopt_redir_protocols... yes
    checking for curlopt_proxy... yes
    checking for curlopt_proxyport... yes
    checking for curlopt_proxytype... yes
    checking for curlopt_noproxy... yes
    checking for curlopt_httpproxytunnel... yes
    checking for curlopt_socks5_gssapi_service... yes
    checking for curlopt_socks5_gssapi_nec... yes
    checking for curlopt_interface... yes
    checking for curlopt_localport... yes
    checking for curlopt_dns_cache_timeout... yes
    checking for curlopt_dns_use_global_cache... yes
    checking for curlopt_buffersize... yes
    checking for curlopt_port... yes
    checking for curlopt_tcp_nodelay... yes
    checking for curlopt_address_scope... yes
    checking for curlopt_netrc... yes
    checking for curl_netrc_optional... yes
    checking for curl_netrc_ignored... yes
    checking for curl_netrc_required... yes
    checking for curlopt_netrc_file... yes
    checking for curlopt_userpwd... yes
    checking for curlopt_proxyuserpwd... yes
    checking for curlopt_username... yes
    checking for curlopt_password... yes
    checking for curlopt_password... yes
    checking for curlopt_password... yes
    checking for curlopt_httpauth... yes
    checking for curlauth_digest_ie... yes
    checking for curlauth_only... yes
    checking for curlopt_tlsauth_type... yes
    checking for curlopt_tlsauth_srp... no
    checking for curlopt_tlsauth_username... yes
    checking for curlopt_tlsauth_password... yes
    checking for curlopt_proxyauth... yes
    checking for curlopt_autoreferer... yes
    checking for curlopt_encoding... yes
    checking for curlopt_followlocation... yes
    checking for curlopt_unrestricted_auth... yes
    checking for curlopt_maxredirs... yes
    checking for curlopt_postredir... yes
    checking for curlopt_put... yes
    checking for curlopt_post... yes
    checking for curlopt_postfields... yes
    checking for curlopt_postfieldsize... yes
    checking for curlopt_postfieldsize_large... yes
    checking for curlopt_copypostfields... yes
    checking for curlopt_httppost... yes
    checking for curlopt_referer... yes
    checking for curlopt_useragent... yes
    checking for curlopt_httpheader... yes
    checking for curlopt_http200aliases... yes
    checking for curlopt_cookie... yes
    checking for curlopt_cookiefile... yes
    checking for curlopt_cookiejar... yes
    checking for curlopt_cookiesession... yes
    checking for curlopt_cookielist... yes
    checking for curlopt_httpget... yes
    checking for curlopt_http_version... yes
    checking for curl_http_version_none... yes
    checking for curl_http_version_1_0... yes
    checking for curl_http_version_1_1... yes
    checking for curlopt_ignore_content_length... yes
    checking for curlopt_http_content_decoding... yes
    checking for curlopt_http_transfer_decoding... yes
    checking for curlopt_mail_from... yes
    checking for curlopt_mail_rcpt... yes
    checking for curlopt_tftp_blksize... yes
    checking for curlopt_ftpport... yes
    checking for curlopt_quote... yes
    checking for curlopt_postquote... yes
    checking for curlopt_prequote... yes
    checking for curlopt_dirlistonly... yes
    checking for curlopt_append... yes
    checking for curlopt_ftp_use_eprt... yes
    checking for curlopt_ftp_use_epsv... yes
    checking for curlopt_ftp_use_pret... yes
    checking for curlopt_ftp_create_missing_dirs... yes
    checking for curlopt_ftp_response_timeout... yes
    checking for curlopt_ftp_alternative_to_user... yes
    checking for curlopt_ftp_skip_pasv_ip... yes
    checking for curlopt_ftpsslauth... yes
    checking for curlftpauth_default... yes
    checking for curlftpauth_ssl... yes
    checking for curlftpauth_tls... yes
    checking for curlopt_ftp_ssl_ccc... yes
    checking for curlftpssl_ccc_none... yes
    checking for curlftpssl_ccc_passive... yes
    checking for curlftpssl_ccc_active... yes
    checking for curlopt_ftp_account... yes
    checking for curlopt_ftp_filemethod... yes
    checking for curlftpmethod_multicwd... yes
    checking for curlftpmethod_nocwd... yes
    checking for curlftpmethod_singlecwd... yes
    checking for curlopt_rtsp_request... yes
    checking for curl_rtspreq_options... yes
    checking for curl_rtspreq_describe... yes
    checking for curl_rtspreq_announce... yes
    checking for curl_rtspreq_setup... yes
    checking for curl_rtspreq_play... yes
    checking for curl_rtspreq_pause... yes
    checking for curl_rtspreq_teardown... yes
    checking for curl_rtspreq_get_parameter... yes
    checking for curl_rtspreq_set_parameter... yes
    checking for curl_rtspreq_record... yes
    checking for curl_rtspreq_receive... yes
    checking for curlopt_rtsp_session_id... yes
    checking for curlopt_rtsp_stream_uri... yes
    checking for curlopt_rtsp_transport... yes
    checking for curlopt_rtsp_header... no
    checking for curlopt_rtsp_client_cseq... yes
    checking for curlopt_rtsp_server_cseq... yes
    checking for curlopt_transfertext... yes
    checking for curlopt_proxy_transfer_mode... yes
    checking for curlopt_crlf... yes
    checking for curlopt_range... yes
    checking for curlopt_resume_from... yes
    checking for curlopt_resume_from_large... yes
    checking for curlopt_customrequest... yes
    checking for curlopt_filetime... yes
    checking for curlopt_nobody... yes
    checking for curlopt_infilesize... yes
    checking for curlopt_infilesize_large... yes
    checking for curlopt_upload... yes
    checking for curlopt_maxfilesize... yes
    checking for curlopt_maxfilesize_large... yes
    checking for curlopt_timecondition... yes
    checking for curlopt_timevalue... yes
    checking for curlopt_timeout... yes
    checking for curlopt_timeout_ms... yes
    checking for curlopt_low_speed_limit... yes
    checking for curlopt_low_speed_time... yes
    checking for curlopt_max_send_speed_large... yes
    checking for curlopt_max_recv_speed_large... yes
    checking for curlopt_maxconnects... yes
    checking for curlopt_closepolicy... yes
    checking for curlopt_fresh_connect... yes
    checking for curlopt_forbid_reuse... yes
    checking for curlopt_connecttimeout... yes
    checking for curlopt_connecttimeout_ms... yes
    checking for curlopt_ipresolve... yes
    checking for curl_ipresolve_whatever... yes
    checking for curl_ipresolve_v4... yes
    checking for curl_ipresolve_v6... yes
    checking for curlopt_connect_only... yes
    checking for curlopt_use_ssl... yes
    checking for curlusessl_none... yes
    checking for curlusessl_try... yes
    checking for curlusessl_control... yes
    checking for curlusessl_all... yes
    checking for curlopt_resolve... yes
    checking for curlopt_sslcert... yes
    checking for curlopt_sslcerttype... yes
    checking for curlopt_sslkey... yes
    checking for curlopt_sslkeytype... yes
    checking for curlopt_keypasswd... yes
    checking for curlopt_sslengine... yes
    checking for curlopt_sslengine_default... yes
    checking for curlopt_sslversion... yes
    checking for curl_sslversion_default... yes
    checking for CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1... yes
    checking for CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2... yes
    checking for CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3... yes
    checking for curlopt_ssl_verifypeer... yes
    checking for curlopt_cainfo... yes
    checking for curlopt_issuercert... yes
    checking for curlopt_capath... yes
    checking for curlopt_crlfile... yes
    checking for curlopt_ssl_verifyhost... yes
    checking for curlopt_certinfo... yes
    checking for curlopt_random_file... yes
    checking for curlopt_egdsocket... yes
    checking for curlopt_ssl_cipher_list... yes
    checking for curlopt_ssl_sessionid_cache... yes
    checking for curlopt_krblevel... yes
    checking for curlopt_ssh_auth_types... yes
    checking for curlopt_ssh_host_public_key_md5... yes
    checking for curlopt_ssh_public_keyfile... yes
    checking for curlopt_ssh_private_keyfile... yes
    checking for curlopt_ssh_knownhosts... yes
    checking for curlopt_ssh_keyfunction... yes
    checking for curlkhstat_fine_add_to_file... yes
    checking for curlkhstat_fine... yes
    checking for curlkhstat_reject... yes
    checking for curlkhstat_defer... yes
    checking for curlopt_ssh_keydata... yes
    checking for curlopt_private... yes
    checking for curlopt_share... yes
    checking for curlopt_new_file_perms... yes
    checking for curlopt_new_directory_perms... yes
    checking for curlopt_telnetoptions... yes
    checking for curle_not_built_in... yes
    checking for curle_obsolete... yes
    checking for Ruby 1.9 Hash... yes
    checking for Ruby 1.9 st.h... yes
    checking for curl_easy_escape... yes
    checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
    creating curb_config.h
    creating Makefile

    make
    compiling curb.c
    compiling curb_postfield.c
    compiling curb_errors.c
    curb_errors.c: In function ‘raise_curl_easy_error_exception’:
    curb_errors.c:462:33: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
    curb_errors.c: In function ‘raise_curl_multi_error_exception’:
    curb_errors.c:512:33: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
    cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
    make: *** [curb_errors.o] Error 1


    Gem files will remain installed in /home/jombay/workspace/nextleap/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.7.18 for inspection.
    Results logged to /home/jombay/workspace/nextleap/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.7.18/ext/gem_make.out
    An error occurred while installing curb (0.7.18), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install curb -v '0.7.18'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The same issue was solved by installing the *libcurl4-opendssl-dev* on ubuntu 12.04. 
Anyone please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u solved this i am still facing the same issue in ubuntu 14.04 ?